# What is git equivalent of the following cvs command

Tags: git, cvs

we are moving from cvs to git.
I want to know what the following cvs commands does and its output

```
cvs -n checkout -p -r${RELEASE} ${MODULE}
```

I also need git equivalent of following cvs command.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I suppose the closest analogy in Git would be `git checkout <branch>`, but I don't think the two commands map 1:1.

Comment: Is there any options which says whether a branch can be cloned and if any issues will be there if cloned, instead of actually cloning the branch?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: The above given cvs command, instead of checking out the module, I think, will report issues that come when checking out. For Eg, if there is no RELEASE in the MODULE, it will report an error instead of checking out entire module and giving error in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if repo exists, if exists 0 is returned else 128 is returned

```
**git ls-remote --heads http://user:pass@github.com:user/repo.git**
```

To check if branch exists in repo, if branch not found no output else one line is printed

```
**git ls-remote --heads http://user:pass@github.com:user/repo.git branch**
```

To check if tag exists in repo, if branch not found no output else on line is printed

```
**git ls-remote --tags http://user:pass@github.com:user/repo.git v7_3**
```

Return code in above 2 cases is 0 always whether branch/tag found or not

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell:

```
   git clone url
```

will give you the whole repository. If then you need to checkout a specific tagged release, you can do

```
 git checkout tags/<tag_name>
```

Even better, you can checkout and create a branch

```
  git checkout tags/<tag_name> -b <branch name>
```

If you only need to clone locally a specific release, try:

```
     git clone --branch <tag_name> <repo_url>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should show the output-errors in checking out the `revision` after the -r option in MODULES. The -n option just simulate  the command you are giving. Anyway, take a look to the [documentation](https://www-e815.fnal.gov/webspace/cvs/commands.html#checkout)

**EDIT/ADDING:**

-r tag: Use the revision specified by the tag argument instead of the default head revision. As well as arbitrary tags defined with the tag or rtag command, two special tags are always available: HEAD refers to the most recent version available in the repository, and BASE refers to the revision you last checked out into the current working directory

Comment: cvs command above dont have two branches to compare, I think.

Comment: Yes, probably i was wrong. I read the global option -r  doc and it says: 
-r tag
Use the revision specified by the tag argument instead of the default head revision. As well as arbitrary tags defined with the tag or rtag command, two special tags are always available: HEAD refers to the most recent version available in the repository, and BASE refers to the revision you last checked out into the current working directory.

So if i'm not mistaking again, whit the command you gave us, you should see if there are errors in checking out the tag revision from MODULES

Comment: I just read above your comment in your question. That's ok! Given +1 ;)