# What is the output of command "cvs -n checkout -p -r${RELEASE} ${MODULE}"

Tags: cvs

Can anybody tell what the output of the following cvs command.

```
cvs -n checkout -p -r${RELEASE} ${MODULE}
```

Especially, will it display any list of files in the {MODULE} ?

Comment: The `-n` option tells CVS not to change any files, so you should be able to see for yourself by running the command. Check the man page for what `-r` and `-p` do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is git equivalent of the following cvs command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218994/what-is-git-equivalent-of-the-following-cvs-command)